# Types of air gaps

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, magnetics

I read the *Transformer and Inductor Design Handbook* and I have some question would like to ask you guys.

1. Why are the EE or EC cores shown in Figure 1-30B the bested suited?
2. Why is only Figure 1-30B lg 1 while  Figure (A), (C), (E) lg are 1/2?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you read about fringing flux noise?

Comment: quite advanced stuff, indeed; I knew about the flux fringe but didn't knew about fringe noise

Comment: @SolarMike,

My question is related to fringing flux noise? if yes, I will read it more.

Comment: @Jitter456 well, you highlighted it... why the airgaps are controlled no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The cores with the gap in the center minimize fringing flux related EMC issues.
2. The loop the magnetic flux travels crosses only one air gap in the cores with a gap in the center leg. The other types have two gaps in series, which behaves similarly to one gap of twice the width provided the core cross-section dimensions are much larger than the gap.

Using a double gap in a core is sometimes useful in testing because you can create various effective gap widths with plastic shim stock and verify the operation, even if it's not good enough for production. In some cases it is good enough, and there are productionized ways of creating a controlled-width gap.

Comment: Hi Spehro,
1.) If the cores with the gap in the center minimize fringing flux, I think figure (A) is the same as figure (B), right?
2.)Figure (A) magnetic flux path is similar to Figure (B, why lg are different? I still don't understand, could you please explain it more?

Comment: @Jitter456 You are correct, the 'E' in A can also be centre-leg ground. The author is confusing what's theoretically possible, with what tends to be commercially available. 'EI' cores only tend to be available in catalogues as ungapped because, well, market sizes and scale of production. If you had a big enough order, you could ask a manufacturer to make centre-gapped EI cores. Also, you will not find the C style of core available anywhere commercially, only the D shape.

Comment: @Neil_UK, 
for 1, Do you know why figure b is the best choice? 
for 2, I still don't understand why the lg is different from others.

Comment: @Jitter456 you're confusing possibility with actuality again. If centre-leg gap, then A and B **don't have gaps in the outer legs** therefore are best for external field. Only B is shown with a centre gap, so all the gap is in the centre. A, C, D are shown with gaps in all legs, so total magnetic gap = 2 x physical gap. Author is confusing A and B, what possibilities are available, and what gets actually sold. Do you know why C is never seen? If you want to wind on bobbins, use D. If you want to wind a toroidal core, use a distrubuted gap toroidal core, not C, to get better external field.

Comment: HI @Neil_UK
How did you get total magnetic gap = 2 x physical gap?
I still don't understand why figure B lg is equal to 1. 
is 2*1/2 = 1?
I don't know why C is never seen, could you please tell me?

Comment: @Jitter456 There is only one gap in B, so the physical gap is the same as the magnetic gap. The other diagrams A, C, D have two gaps magnetically in series, so the total magnetic gap is twice the physical gap.

Comment: @Jitter456 D will take bobbins, C will not (wrong shape). Bobbins are cheaper to wind than a toroid, so if you can accept the external field, D beats C. If you're going to the expense of winding a toroid, then you wouldn't use the two discrete air-gaps of C that give you a strong external field, you would use a 'distributed air gap' core, make from ferrite dust in epoxy, which is uniform, so has a low external field. There is no commercial reason to bring C to the market, so it's never seen.

Comment: Interestingly, there are toroidal cores with a single gap available off the shelf. Metglas.

Answer (score 1):

Air gaps in magnetic cores are sources of Electromagnetic Noise, also called fringing flux, and they might affect nearby conducting objects in a negative way. For example, gaps in lateral columns are bad when using metal clamps to hold the core together because they induce eddy current on the clamps, which reduces the efficiency of the system and can cause heating problems.
To avoid this, consumer magnetics tend to have gap only in the center column/pole, so the rest of columns/poles of the core shields the exterior from the fringing flux. This shielding is better in cores that which lateral columns cover more angle, like PQ, RM, PQ, or even close to 360º, like P cores.

My guess on what McLyman means saying that the (B) cores are best suited is that (A) cores is that on the later the gaps are on the lateral columns, where nothing is shielding this fringing flux. But must also be noticed that (A) core is much cheaper to manufacture than (B), so they are also used in practice.

About your second question, the best approach is to focus on one of the paths that the magnetic flux can take inside the core. They are marked with a discontinued line on the picture, and there are two paths for (A) and (B), and only one for (C) and (D).

If we take the right path in (A), we can see how the line crosses two gaps of 1/2, so the total distance that the flux must travel through air is 1 unit.

If we also take the right path in (B), we can see how the line crosses on gap of 1, and another of 0, so the total distance traveled through air is also 1 unit. It must be noticed that there is no gap on the lateral columns in case (B), only in the center column/pole.

My guess is that the author wanted to have equivalent gap length in the four examples, but disitributed in a different way.

I would like to add one remark before I finish: I assumed that the gap in lateral legs of (B) have 0 gap. This is not true in reality, as there is always a small gap when putting to pieces together, called residual gap, which is around 2-10um on commercial shapes. But that is an advanced topic and this is a basic example.